# Modifying parameter values "rqt_reconfigure" using a python script

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi

How can I change a parameter that is available on the "rqt_reconfigure" interface using a python script? For example, I would like to change the "max_vel_x" parameter from a certain place automatically, using a script.

thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/359120/modifying-parameter-values-%22rqt_reconfigure%22-using-a-python-script/) by [mateusguilherme](https://answers.ros.org/users/39228/mateusguilherme/) on ROS Answers with karma: 125 on 2020-08-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

complete example

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import dynamic_reconfigure.client
import rospy

rospy.init_node('rs_config_modifier', anonymous=True)

exposure_roi_client = dynamic_reconfigure.client.Client("camera/stereo_module/auto_exposure_roi",timeout=60)
hole_filling_client = dynamic_reconfigure.client.Client("camera/hole_filling",timeout=60)

exposure_roi_params = { 'left' : 169, 'right' : 678, 'top' : 95, 'bottom' : 384 }
exposure_roi_client.update_configuration(exposure_roi_params)

hole_filling_params = { 'holes_fill' : 2}
hole_filling_client.update_configuration(hole_filling_params)
```

---

Originally posted by [Ahmed Osman](https://answers.ros.org/users/36991/ahmed-osman/) with karma: 56 on 2020-09-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You should check [this wiki](http://wiki.ros.org/hokuyo_node/Tutorials/UsingDynparamToChangeHokuyoLaserParameters#Using_dynamic_reconfigure_from_Python_code) that explains how to use the dynamic reconfigure python API. To detail what you need here :

Import the client :

```
import dynamic_reconfigure.client
```

Create a client instance of the node to reconfigure :

```
node_name=<node_to_reconfigure>
client = dynamic_reconfigure.client.Client(node_name)
```

Make sure to give the full name of the node if you have prefixes, the client will look for the service `node_name/set_parameters`, you can check with `rosservice list` the propper node name instead of using `rosnode list` (if the dynamic reconfigure server has been created under another nodehandle for example).

And calling `update_configuration` with a dictionary of changes to make :

```
#params = { 'my_string_parameter' : 'value', 'my_int_parameter' : 5 }
params = { 'max_vel_x' : 5.0 }
config = client.update_configuration(params)
```

---

Originally posted by [Delb](https://answers.ros.org/users/33811/delb/) with karma: 3907 on 2020-08-10

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1